# How to call a function after pipe() has completed in angularfire

Tags: angular, asynchronous, pipe, angularfire

I have a really simple problem but it has caused me hours of frustration.

I have an observable snapshot from angular firebase which I am piping through the map function to change some of the data.

like so:

```
this.itemsList = this.itemsRefList.snapshotChanges().pipe(
  map(changes =>
    changes.map(c => ({
      product: c.payload.key,
      firmware: c.payload.child('latest').val(),
      ref: c.payload.ref,
    })
    )
  )
);
```

After the pipe has *finished* I would like to simply call a function, how can I achieve this?

Specifically, I am using ngx-admin, and have a card whose content defaults to a loading spinner.

```
<nb-card>
 <nb-card-header>
...
 </nb-card-header>
 <nb-card-body [nbSpinner]="tableDataLoading" nbSpinnerSize="giant" nbSpinnerStatus="warning">
  <div *ngIf="itemsList | async as items">
    <ng2-smart-table [settings]="settings" [source]="items"></ng2-smart-table>
  </div>
 </nb-card-body>
</nb-card>
```

As soon as my itemList is populated, I want to call a function that sets tableDataLoading to false, so the spinner disappears.

What is the correct way to do this, I have tried many things, including subscribing to itemsList, and trying to call a function on that (tells me it's not a function), attempting to see if I can change the variable in the html template somehow - to no avail etc etc

Comment: Just add a .tap after the map..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a bracket in changes.map function.

```
this.itemsList = this.itemsRefList.snapshotChanges().pipe(
  map(changes =>{
   let temp = changes.map(c => ({
      product: c.payload.key,
      firmware: c.payload.child('latest').val(),
      ref: c.payload.ref,
    }))
   //map is done, call other code here
   this.callOtherMethodHere();
   return temp;
  })
);
```

Comment: if I try this, the complier complains with 

Type 'Observable<void>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any[]>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.

Comment: Great, thank you for your help, I just had to remove the penultimate ;

 return temp;
  }); <--this one

To get it to compile